# Installing CppCheck on Codeblocks

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, cppcheck

I have downloaded Codeblocks in a Windows 10 computer and now I am trying to install CppCheck on it.

However, also surfing the net to find a solution, I can't understand how can I install CppCheck (on Codeblocks). 
Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: [http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) says its integrated.

Comment: This may help: [http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=18895.0](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=18895.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to follow :

- Download [Codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26)

  - Cppcheck is a Contrib plugin integrated in Codeblocks
  - So, choose the setup from the download page which has all the plugins available
- Install Codeblocks

  - Make sure Cppcheck plugin is selected under Contrib plugins
- Install [Cppcheck tool](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) for your respective platform
- Open Codeblocks and open the Environment Settings via the Settings Menu

  - Scroll down and select the Cppcheck/Vera++ Tab
  - Change the Cppcheck application field by clicking on the button with `...`
  - Navigate to the path where Cppcheck tool was installed (Ex: `C:\Program Files\Cppcheck\cppcheck.exe`)
  - Click OK
- Open a project in Codeblocks and under Plugins Menu select CppCheck to run the tool